# How to add a label to an issue using GitHub API?

Tags: rest, github

I'm trying to find a way to add a label to a GitHub issue using the API. After checking the [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#add-labels-to-an-issue) I tried the following `curl` request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO" -H  \
     "Accept: application/vnd.github.symmetra-preview+json" \
     -d @label.json https://api.github.com/repos/CHSUNSONG/star-platform/issues/11
```

`label.json` contains:

```
["submitted"]
```

However, I got the following response:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid request.\n\nFor 'links/1/schema', [\"submitted\"] is not an object.",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue"
}
```

Why isn't this working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You're POSTing to the wrong URL. Add `/labels` onto the end:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO" -H  \
     "Accept: application/vnd.github.symmetra-preview+json" \
     -d @label.json \
     https://api.github.com/repos/CHSUNSONG/star-platform/issues/11/labels
```